# Is there a SoC for IoT with cellular network, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, soc

I am looking for SoC with support for cellular network, Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. In fact, any Mediatek is suitable, but I am an individual and no one will sign an agreement with me, I suppose. Yes, and I do not want to use two modules, for example ESP32 and SIM800, because I plan to make a very small device and every square centimeter counts.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic here. Also, the way you're asking here (and the products you mention) indicate that you wouldn't even remotely have the machinery nor design nor testing skills to build something as compact as a smart phone; I doubt your second IC will be the size problem (it isn't even in smart phones).

Comment: Look, I can't find any StackExchange site for "product recomendation", so I thought this site is closest, as I am searching for electrical component.
I had exprerience in schematic-pcb-SMT-writing arduino firmware to create my diy esp32 watch. But now I am looking for same thing as esp32 but with cellurar network support for GPRS. So I checked out what modules are using others. Arduino use SIM800, but I don't want separate module for size reasons. The closest that I found on my own is Ai-Tinker A9, which has cellurar and I can run my code on it as SDK is open, but no wifi/bluetooth.

Comment: The fact that you can't find a site where it's on-topic doesn't make it on-topic here, sorry. Also, there's A BIG leap from "a full SIM800 and a full ESP32 and some device that has 'tinker' in its name" to trying to make a smartphone SoC work, really. Like, several years of professional experience required kind of leap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being an individual consumer not a company may limit your ability to get such chips. If you want the three technologies together: Cellular, WiFi and Bluetooth you are basically asking for a Smartphone SoC!

If you are developing for IoT, notice that you are typically designing a small product targeting low power and cost. So I don't think it makes since to have that much of wireless variety in a small IoT product with the given constraints.

To let you know, Some IoT products can rely solely on BLE, WiFi or Cellular, ANT or Zigbee or a combination of both.

Anyway, if you want some products having multiple technologies, you can check:

1- Nordic Semiconductor (Cellular) https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-cellular-IoT

2- Nordic Semiconductor (Bluetooth, Zigbee): https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/nRF5340

3- Texas Instruments (WiFi): http://www.ti.com/wireless-connectivity/products.html#p367=Wi-Fi%202.4GHz

4- NXP Semiconductors (Wifi, Bluetooth): https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/wi-fi-plus-bluetooth:WIFI-BLUETOOTH